# How to filter files with regex by extension but exclude some files?

Tags: regex

I want to filter files that have extension `.htm`, `.html`, `.js`, `.css`, `.svg`, `.png` but exclude files that have names `index.html`, `page1.html`.

To filter files by extension I use this regex: `\.(htm|html|js|css|svg|png)$`.

But how can I exclude files with names `index.html`, `page1.html`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude files:

```
^(?!(index|page1)\.html$).*\.(htm|html|js|css|svg|png)$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/DjXaWR/1)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using Regex - use Linq.  Not so concise but...

```
var includeExtensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    {".htm", ".html", ".js", ".css", ".svg", ".png", ".txt"};

var excludeNames = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    {"index", "page1"};

var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\test")
    .Select(f => new {FileName = f, Ext=Path.GetExtension(f), Name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)})
    .Where(f => includeExtensions.Contains(f.Ext))
    .Where(f => !excludeNames.Contains(f.Name))
    .Select(f => f.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this :

```
(?<!index|page1)(.html|.htm|.css|.js|.png|.svg)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZXVai/1)